# How to make Nginx spawn fcgi file

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I have a .fcgi file that works with Apache, I just point the rewrite rules to the file and it does its job, but it seems Nginx is not able to work like this.

On Apache, I would just redirect the requests to the file. As from the original project .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /matrufsc
RewriteRule ^dispatch\.fcgi/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

So every request except from trying to access root is routed to `dispatch.fcgi/$request`. But Nginx is uncapable of executing files directly. What alternatives do I have to execute this file?

It is a python script that filters requests and takes action depending on requested "file". You can see the script source [here at GitHub](https://github.com/ranisalt/capim/blob/master/py/dispatch.fcgi), and it works like this for Apache with the above htaccess. I have no knowledge of how to work with FastCGI.

How do I spawn a fastcgi process from Nginx? I have no clue on it or how to describe it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to use a module called fastcgi.

The docs are here [FastCGI Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html).

An example location

```
location / {
    fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www/scripts/php$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
}
```

This will also require a fastcgi daemon running as well.  Installation of this daemon depends on your os.

Here is another page on the wiki that talks about fcgi.

http://wiki.nginx.org/FcgiExample

Comment: Fine. Combined with `spawn-fcgi`, I managed to make it work. I just needed the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` param as all others are included in `fastcgi_params` that I include!